# Regex isn't replacing all of the requested characters

Tags: regex

Currently, given the string to manipulate is abXYabcXYZ, I want to remove anything that isn't "abc", all together. My regex command is like so:

```
[^abc]
```

which returns ab++abc+++, when I need to to return ++++abc+++. If I use the same string to manipulate, but only replace anything that isn't "ab", I'll get ab++ab++++, which is correct. How do I make it so the first test won't add in the ab, when it's missing the c?

Comment: The regex is completely wrong. `[^abc]` means match any character that's not an `a`, a `b` or a `c`. And what do you mean by "regex command"? What exactly are you using?

Comment: To understand the error of your ways, try using `axxxbxxxxcccxxxbbbbx` as input to either regex.

Comment: Try [^abc]+  as there is more than one element in a row.

Comment: @NiallByrne That's even wronger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by NullUserException ఠ_ఠ, the regular expression [^abc] means any single character that's not `a`, `b` or `c`.

Using this regular expression to perform replacement on `ab++abc+++` will only replace `+` (`+` is [^abc]) to `+` (I think you're replacing [^abc] to `+`) resulting that the string remains the same.

As for the second situation, I suppose that you want to use a regular expression [^ab], which will match the characters `c` and `+` and get the result `ab++ab++++`.

That explains why you've got that. I don't really know whether there is any regular expression that matches both `\w+` and not a specific string like `abc`. And in some situation you can achieve this by replace `abc` to another string which is not a character such as `%`, and replace all `\w` to `+`, and then replace `%` back to `abc`.

Hope that it is helpful.